# Fail to access WSDL outside of localhost

Tags: vb.net, wcf, wsdl

I have my server hosting my WSDL on an app server. I'm able to access the service and use the methods when running locally off my own IP address. But when running on our app server I can only access the WSDL, reference it and view the methods it has, but not use the methods. I'm running it as a console application in VB.NET 4.0. I get an InternalServiceFault.

```
Public Class pokeWCF
   Implements poke

   Dim objFile As String = "C:\Users\lsj\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleServer\easyA.txt"
   Dim aryText() As String
   Dim sK As String
   Dim fM As String
   Dim msg As String
   Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Now
   Dim format As String = "ddd d HH:mm yyyy"
   Dim OracleReceive As New ReceiveOrcl

   Public Function backTo(securityKey As String, from As String, message As String) As ServiceResult Implements poke.backTo
   'stuff
   End Function

   Public Function Test(securityKey As String) As ServiceResult Implements poke.Test
   'moreStuff
   End Function
End Class

Sub Main()
    Dim strHostName As String
    Dim strIPAddress As String
    strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()

    strIPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(strHostName).AddressList(0).ToString()
    MsgBox(strIPAddress.ToString)

    Dim url As Uri = New Uri("http://" & strIPAddress & ":22380/poke")
    Dim host As New ServiceHost(GetType(pokeWCF), url)
    Dim smb As New ServiceMetadataBehavior()
    Console.WriteLine("CRAB BATTLE!")
    Console.Write("Server Up" & vbCrLf)

    smb.HttpGetEnabled = True
    smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb)
    host.Open()

    Console.WriteLine("Running at " & url.ToString)
    Console.Read()

End Sub
```

After looking over the WSDLs generated from the app server and my localhost vary in their definitions.

Edit:

Locally generated WSDL:

```
 <wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="RacoSMSWCF" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<xs:import namespace="https://t-mobile.racowireless.com/SMSRicochet1.0"/>
<xs:element name="ReceiveSMS">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="securityKey" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="from" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="message" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="ReceiveSMSResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element xmlns:q1="https://t-mobile.racowireless.com/SMSRicochet1.0" minOccurs="0" name="ReceiveSMSResult" type="q1:ServiceResult"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Test">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="securityKey" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="TestResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element xmlns:q2="https://t-mobile.racowireless.com/SMSRicochet1.0" minOccurs="0" name="TestResult" type="q2:ServiceResult"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
<xs:element name="anyType" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"/>
<xs:element name="anyURI" nillable="true" type="xs:anyURI"/>
<xs:element name="base64Binary" nillable="true" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
<xs:element name="boolean" nillable="true" type="xs:boolean"/>
<xs:element name="byte" nillable="true" type="xs:byte"/>
<xs:element name="dateTime" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime"/>
<xs:element name="decimal" nillable="true" type="xs:decimal"/>
<xs:element name="double" nillable="true" type="xs:double"/>
<xs:element name="float" nillable="true" type="xs:float"/>
<xs:element name="int" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element name="long" nillable="true" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element name="QName" nillable="true" type="xs:QName"/>
<xs:element name="short" nillable="true" type="xs:short"/>
<xs:element name="string" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedByte" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedByte"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedInt" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedLong" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedLong"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedShort" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedShort"/>
<xs:element name="char" nillable="true" type="tns:char"/>
<xs:simpleType name="char">
<xs:restriction base="xs:int"/>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="duration" nillable="true" type="tns:duration"/>
<xs:simpleType name="duration">
<xs:restriction base="xs:duration">
<xs:pattern value="\-?P(\d*D)?(T(\d*H)?(\d*M)?(\d*(\.\d*)?S)?)?"/>
<xs:minInclusive value="-P10675199DT2H48M5.4775808S"/>
<xs:maxInclusive value="P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="guid" nillable="true" type="tns:guid"/>
<xs:simpleType name="guid">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:pattern value="[\da-fA-F]{8}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{12}"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:attribute name="FactoryType" type="xs:QName"/>
<xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:ID"/>
<xs:attribute name="Ref" type="xs:IDREF"/>
</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="https://t-mobile.racowireless.com/SMSRicochet1.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="https://t-mobile.racowireless.com/SMSRicochet1.0">
<xs:simpleType name="ServiceResult">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:enumeration value="ACCEPTED"/>
<xs:enumeration value="MESSAGE_TOO_LONG"/>
<xs:enumeration value="INVALID_CREDENTIALS"/>
<xs:enumeration value="REJECTED"/>
<xs:enumeration value="NOTFOUND"/>
<xs:enumeration value="INVALID_RECIPIENT"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="ServiceResult" nillable="true" type="tns:ServiceResult"/>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="racoSMS_ReceiveSMS_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ReceiveSMS"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="racoSMS_ReceiveSMS_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ReceiveSMSResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="racoSMS_Test_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Test"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="racoSMS_Test_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:TestResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="racoSMS">
<wsdl:operation name="ReceiveSMS">
<wsdl:input wsam:Action="http://tempuri.org/racoSMS/ReceiveSMS" message="tns:racoSMS_ReceiveSMS_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsam:Action="http://tempuri.org/racoSMS/ReceiveSMSResponse" message="tns:racoSMS_ReceiveSMS_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="Test">
<wsdl:input wsam:Action="http://tempuri.org/racoSMS/Test" message="tns:racoSMS_Test_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsam:Action="http://tempuri.org/racoSMS/TestResponse" message="tns:racoSMS_Test_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_racoSMS" type="tns:racoSMS">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="ReceiveSMS">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/racoSMS/ReceiveSMS" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="Test">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/racoSMS/Test" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="RacoSMSWCF">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_racoSMS" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_racoSMS">
<soap:address location="http://192.168.100.88:22380/racoSMS"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

App Server WSDL:

```
     <wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" name="RacoSMSWCF" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<xs:import namespace="https://t-mobile.racowireless.com/SMSRicochet1.0"/>
<xs:element name="ReceiveSMS">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="securityKey" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="from" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="message" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="ReceiveSMSResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element xmlns:q1="https://t-mobile.racowireless.com/SMSRicochet1.0" minOccurs="0" name="ReceiveSMSResult" type="q1:ServiceResult"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Test">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="securityKey" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="TestResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element xmlns:q2="https://t-mobile.racowireless.com/SMSRicochet1.0" minOccurs="0" name="TestResult" type="q2:ServiceResult"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
<xs:element name="anyType" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"/>
<xs:element name="anyURI" nillable="true" type="xs:anyURI"/>
<xs:element name="base64Binary" nillable="true" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
<xs:element name="boolean" nillable="true" type="xs:boolean"/>
<xs:element name="byte" nillable="true" type="xs:byte"/>
<xs:element name="dateTime" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime"/>
<xs:element name="decimal" nillable="true" type="xs:decimal"/>
<xs:element name="double" nillable="true" type="xs:double"/>
<xs:element name="float" nillable="true" type="xs:float"/>
<xs:element name="int" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element name="long" nillable="true" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element name="QName" nillable="true" type="xs:QName"/>
<xs:element name="short" nillable="true" type="xs:short"/>
<xs:element name="string" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedByte" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedByte"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedInt" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedLong" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedLong"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedShort" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedShort"/>
<xs:element name="char" nillable="true" type="tns:char"/>
<xs:simpleType name="char">
<xs:restriction base="xs:int"/>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="duration" nillable="true" type="tns:duration"/>
<xs:simpleType name="duration">
<xs:restriction base="xs:duration">
<xs:pattern value="\-?P(\d*D)?(T(\d*H)?(\d*M)?(\d*(\.\d*)?S)?)?"/>
<xs:minInclusive value="-P10675199DT2H48M5.4775808S"/>
<xs:maxInclusive value="P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="guid" nillable="true" type="tns:guid"/>
<xs:simpleType name="guid">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:pattern value="[\da-fA-F]{8}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{12}"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:attribute name="FactoryType" type="xs:QName"/>
<xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:ID"/>
<xs:attribute name="Ref" type="xs:IDREF"/>
</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="https://t-mobile.racowireless.com/SMSRicochet1.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="https://t-mobile.racowireless.com/SMSRicochet1.0">
<xs:simpleType name="ServiceResult">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:enumeration value="ACCEPTED"/>
<xs:enumeration value="MESSAGE_TOO_LONG"/>
<xs:enumeration value="INVALID_CREDENTIALS"/>
<xs:enumeration value="REJECTED"/>
<xs:enumeration value="NOTFOUND"/>
<xs:enumeration value="INVALID_RECIPIENT"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="ServiceResult" nillable="true" type="tns:ServiceResult"/>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="racoSMS_ReceiveSMS_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ReceiveSMS"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="racoSMS_ReceiveSMS_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ReceiveSMSResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="racoSMS_Test_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Test"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="racoSMS_Test_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:TestResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="racoSMS">
<wsdl:operation name="ReceiveSMS">
<wsdl:input wsam:Action="http://tempuri.org/racoSMS/ReceiveSMS" message="tns:racoSMS_ReceiveSMS_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsam:Action="http://tempuri.org/racoSMS/ReceiveSMSResponse" message="tns:racoSMS_ReceiveSMS_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="Test">
<wsdl:input wsam:Action="http://tempuri.org/racoSMS/Test" message="tns:racoSMS_Test_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsam:Action="http://tempuri.org/racoSMS/TestResponse" message="tns:racoSMS_Test_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_racoSMS" type="tns:racoSMS">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="ReceiveSMS">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/racoSMS/ReceiveSMS" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="Test">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/racoSMS/Test" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="RacoSMSWCF">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_racoSMS" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_racoSMS">
<soap:address location="http://192.168.200.27:22380/racoSMS"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Edit:

Having discovered WCF Test Client from I got this error after testing my service running on the server.

```
 The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at racoSMS.Test(String securityKey)
   at racoSMSClient.Test(String securityKey)
```

Comment: Could you also post the code that you are using to consume the service on the client side?

Comment: I've been using soapUI to consume the service. We have a provider that's supposed to be connecting to our server so I'm not sure of how they implemented it. I'm trying to clear everything on my end first.

Comment: Posted a solution below that should fix your problem.

Comment: It looks like the WSDLs contain the same information, though in a different order.  Are the contents the same (wsdl:types/portType/binding/service...)?  Could you post those?

Comment: I've each of the WSDLs to the OP. When I compare one to the other they only vary in their definitions and their serviceendpoints.

I'd like to believe I'm overlooking something simple that would result in this only working locally.

Comment: Can you give more information on the InternalServiceFault you're getting?

Comment: I've tried to use the server trace logs but haven't been able to get it to work.
"The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the &lt;serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs."

Comment: This entire time I was led to believe there was something wrong with how my WSDL was being hosted. And all the errors I had and would receive looked as if it was something server related. 

The code I never shared was a snippet of code that connected to our Oracle Database that would read and write to it. Those having commented it out and tested it was able to invoke the wsdl effectively.

Comment: Glad you were able to get to the root of the problem and resolve it!

Answer (score 1):

You have created the ServiceHost and set up a ServiceMetadataBehavior with HttpGetEnabled so that the service WSDL can be accessed at the address http://?wsdl.  It looks like the only thing missing is the endpoints that need to be added to the ServiceHost.

You can add endpoints with the following syntax:

```
host.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType([ServiceContractType]), [binding], "[url]");
```

The ServiceContract type should be implemented by your service class (it's often an interface and looks like it's "poke" in this case).

There are many bindings available (more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734662.aspx)), and what you use will depend on what kinds of clients you want to support and what kind of features you want to provide (security, reliability, transactions, etC).  BasicHttpBinding is the most backward-compatible and will work with anything that conforms to the WS-I Basic Profile specification.

The url you provide in the endpoint will be appended to the base url you provided to the ServiceHost when that object was created.

Comment: I noticed this is automatically added to the WSDL when compiled but I've done it explicitly as you've suggested. The problem still persists even when running on the app server. 

I noticed that the WSDL definitions generated vary from one another(posted in OP).

Comment: Edit: when a adding the endpoint I used the the IP from whichever computer is running my server program.